Web Worker Thread Pool
I have developed a Javascript Excel Add-in that uses a Web Worker to make background / long-running service API requests. The user determines how many requests need to be made, and the results are then written to a worksheet in the workbook. This works fine, however as the number of requests increases the serice API provider can get overwhelmed.
Ideally I would like to have some sort of thread pool of Web Workers that could process the API requests from a queue - per the following example in Java:
https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava

The number of worker threads could be configured by the user based upon the API service provider capabilities.
Based upon a search of the site I cannot find any precedent, and would appreciate thoughts.
Cheers,
Andrew

You need a thread or worker pool only for expensive computations. You do not need it for asynchronous requests, a simple queue or connection pool will suffice. Search for "limit number of parallel requests", there are thousands of questions about it.
